# URL not found error when php has to send serial data

Tags: php, html, linux, serial-port

Here is the code I'm using to communicate with a microcontroller.

Everything works, however when I click on the link html, which is supposed to send data through serial i get:

```
http://project.sonar.com/%3C?=$_SERVER[%27PHP_SELF%27]%20.
The requested URL /< was not found on this server.
```

I know the communication initialization works, since this problem occurred only when I added the link

```
    if (isset($_GET['action']))
    {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');     //displays php errors


        include("php_serial.class.php");



        $serial = new phpSerial();
        //$serial -> deviceClose(); 
        $serial->deviceSet('/dev/ttyUSB0'); //for linux serial /dev/ttySP(0-4) for usb /dev/ttyUSBN

        // If you want to change the configuration, the device must be closed 

        $serial->confBaudRate(9600); //Baud rate: 9600
        $serial->confParity("none");  //Parity (this is the "N" in "8-N-1")
        $serial->confCharacterLength(8); //Character length (this is the "8" in "8-N-1")
        $serial->confStopBits(2);  //Stop bits (this is the "1" in "8-N-1")
        $serial->confFlowControl("none");
        $serial->deviceOpen();

            if ($_GET['action'] == "on") 
                {
                // To write into $serial->sendMessage("1");
                for ($x = 1; $x < 20; $x++)
                $serial->sendMessage("1");
                }

    $read = $serial->readPort(); //read stores acii value from controller
    if($read > "0")
    {
        $numberz = 20*ord($read);    // number converts the value to decimal representation of distance
        //echo "$numberz";  
        //$database="MEASURE";

        $username = "xxxx";
        $password = "xxxx";
        $hostname = "xxxx";

        $connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
            if (!$connection)
              {
              die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
              }

        mysql_select_db("MEASURE", $connection);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO measurement (DATA)
        VALUES
        ('$numberz')");
    }

    else
        {
        $serial -> deviceClose();
        }
}


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">


        <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle" media="screen">
        @import "style.css";
        </style>

    <body>
    <p><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=on" ?>">
    Click here to turn the system on.</a></p>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="top">


            <ul id="mainmenu">
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="measurement2.php">MEASUREMENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="report.html">REPORT</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacts.html">CONTACTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="pictop">
            <img src="pics/header.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <div id="main">

        <div id="indexleft">
        <h2>Table</h2>




<?php
    //$database="MEASURE";
    $username = "xxxx";
    $password = "xxxx";
    $hostname = "xxxx";

    $connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
        if (!$connection)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

    mysql_select_db("MEASURE", $connection);



    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM measurement"); 

    echo "<table width='80%' border='4px'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>DATA</th>
    <th>TIME</th>
    </tr>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";              
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['data'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['TIME'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_close($connection);
?>          


        </div>

            <div id="bottom">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Possibly your short tags on this line: `<a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=on" ?>">`. [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/200666/1134705)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server probably does not have short tags enabled.

Change:

```
<p><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=on" ?>">
```

to:

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=on"; ?>">
```

although you could probably change it to just:

```
<p><a href="?action=on">
```

Answer (score 0):

The %3c in your URL is the < character. It is not surprising that there is no directory or file called <. Change where you write the link to:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=on"; ?>
```

Comment: well thats how the link looks like                                 <p><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=on" ?>">
    Click here to turn the system on. </a></p> As much as i understand PHP_SELF would point to the same directory

Comment: And it is wrong. it is telling you that the link does not exist. BTW, you are using short open tags which have been deprecated for years! See my edit for correct code.